# EditText com mesmo tamanho Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Gostaria de deixar meus componentes `<EditText/>` com o mesmo tamanho mas não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AUTO"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText13" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText14" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText14" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="Principal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/auto"
        android:text="Automoveis" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/portateis"
        android:text="Portáties" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/empresarial"
        android:text="Empresarial" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/residencial"
        android:text="Residencial" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/travel"
        android:text="Viagem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        android:text="Formulario Para Orçamento de Seguro" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Dados Pessoais" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Proponente" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText12" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText11"
        android:text="Telefone Residencial" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText11"
        android:text="Telefone Comercial" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText13"
        android:text="Celular" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText14"

        android:text="FAX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:text="Email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEstado_civil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText12"
        android:text="Estado Civil" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEstado_civil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEstado_civil" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextEstado_civil"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText12"
        android:text="Data" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextData"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextEstado_civil"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextEstado_civil"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextEstado_civil"
        android:text="RG" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtRG" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCorrentista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:text="Correntista qual banco?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCorrentista"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextRG" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEndereco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextRG"
        android:text="Endereco" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEndereco" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCEP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:text="CEP" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCEP"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextEndereco"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextEndereco" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCNH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCEP"
        android:text="CNH" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCNH" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDataExpedicao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:text="Data de expedição" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextData_expedicao"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFinanciado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCNH"
        android:text="O carro está financiado ?" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFinanciado"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFinanciado" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextFinanciado"
        android:text="Dados do Veiculo"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMarca"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDados"
        android:text="Marca/Modelo"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMarca" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPortas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:text="Portas" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPortas"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCombustivel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextMArca"
        android:text="Combustivel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCombustivel" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:text="Cor" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCor"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFabricacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCombustivel"
        android:text="Ano de Fabricação" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFabricacao"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFabricacao" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtModelo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtFabricacao"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtFabricacao"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Ano Modelo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAno"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextFabricacao"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextFabricacao"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRenavan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextFabricacao"
        android:text="Renavan" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextRenavan"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtRenavan" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtRenavan"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtRenavan"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:text="Qual a cia ?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCia"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextRenavan"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextRenavan"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
       </RelativeLatout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para cada uma das linhas que você tiver, você pode agrupar dois `EditText` ou `TextView` (ou mais, mas com risco de ficar extremamente pequeno) em um `LinearLayout` e definir um "peso" máximo para as views dentro dele com `android:weightSum`. E como, no seu caso, a orientação é horizontal, em cada um dos `EditText` você define o `android:layout_width` como 0dp e define um "peso" para ele próprio através da propriedade `android:layout_weight`, conforme o exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```